# How can I decide to call an overrided method in child class from either parent or child class?

Tags: c#, python

I am going to implement below C# piece of code in Python. As a matter of fact, when I instantiate an object from class B, I am prone to get some flexibility to choose between the parent-version or child version of the overrided method, just like below:

```
class A
{
    public virtual void show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Print A");
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public override void show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Print B");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a;
        a = new A();
        a.show();

        a = new B();
        a.show();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Where the output is:

```
Print A
Print B
```

But I have no clear idea to the same with super keyword in python. I have written below code:

```
class A(object):
    def f(self):
        print("A.f()")

class B(A):
    def f(self):
        print("B.f()")
        return super().f()

b = B()
b.f()
```

where the output is:

```
B.f()
A.f()
```

which is not my desired output; in the latter case, i.e. Python one, the two strings are generated just by one method call.

Would you please help me to change the python code so that the desired output is acquired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you didn't want `A.f()` to be called, nothing forces you to use `super().f()`:

```
class A(object):
    def f(self):
        print("A.f()")

class B(A):
    def f(self):
        print("B.f()")

a = A()
a.f()
b = B()
b.f()
```

The above does exactly what your C# code does; create two separate instances and invokes `f()` on each, where `B.f()` completely replaces what `A.f()` does.

You can still take the *unbound* function from `A` and pass in an instance of `B()`:

```
b = B()
A.f(b)  # unbound A.f(), passing in an instance of `B`
```

or you could look up the parent method without a reference to the parent class with:

```
super(type(b), b).f()
```

This is however quite different from your original C# sample.

Comment: @Martjin Pieters: Actually, the order of the printing sequence does not really matter!... As I illustrated above, When I call the function f() by unique object b, I am going to choose among the f() in class A and f() in class B to be run; not both of them.
In other words, I am prone to rewrite the code so that for each string in output, there is a correspondent function calling, just like C# piece of code.

Comment: @matinking: you don't do either in the C# code; you created an instance of class `A`, then of `B`, and called `f()` on both. The C# code doesn't invoke the parent method, the Python code *does*. Simply remove the `super()` call if you didn't want that.

Comment: @Martjin Pieters: Let's just assume that we remove that super calling. In this case, Is there any way to access to the parent f() function by the b object, is which instantiated from the child class?!

Comment: @Martjin Pieters: Bingo!... Thank you very much. This is exactly what. I'm looking for. I need to get some investigation upon the unbounded functions and the second approach, taken into account by you, as I'm a newcomer in the Python territory!